# Attempted to call function "mb_convert_case" from namespace "FOS\UserBundle\Util

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I have deployed my symfony2 app to heroku. I am using fos and sonata user bundle. during creating user from terminal. i got following error.

 `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException]

  Attempted to call function "mb_convert_case" from namespace "FOS\UserBundle\Util".`

then i run `heroku run php app/check.php` and got below result.

```
Symfony2 Requirements Checker
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
  /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php.ini

> Checking Symfony requirements:
  ......................W....W.W.....


 [OK]                                          
 Your system is ready to run Symfony2 projects 


Optional recommendations to improve your setup
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

 * mb_strlen() should be available
   > Install and enable the mbstring extension.

 * intl extension should be available
   > Install and enable the intl extension (used for validators).

 * short_open_tag should be disabled in php.ini
   > Set short_open_tag to off in php.ini*.


Note  The command console could use a different php.ini file
~~~~  than the one used with your web server. To be on the
      safe side, please check the requirements from your web
      server using the web/config.php script.
```

Have also put `"ext-mbstring": "*",` to `composer.json`, but still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the system you run your project on doesn't have php-mbstring extension, you must enable it.

Did you run a composer install after adding "ext-mbstring": "*" ? This should have fix this problem.

Related thread :

[FOSuserBundle and php 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955570/fosuserbundle-and-php-5-5)

[PHP Multibyte String on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656247/php-multibyte-string-on-heroku)